# Problem with FilteringCriteria in Google Apps Script// Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, filtering, criteria

How are you? I'm working on Google Apps Script and what I want to achieve is to set the filter on the selected cells with the criteria I need. However, even though I specify the filter, the desired criteria are not being established. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Here it's the code:

```
var headersRange = sheet.getRange("M5:X5");
headersRange.createFilter();

// Filtrar en la columna S5 por valores mayores al 60%
var filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().GreaterThan(0.6).build();
var filter = headersRange.getFilter();
filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(19, filterCriteria); // Columna S

// Filtrar en la columna T5 por valores entre -50% y 50%
var filterCriteriaT = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .NumberGreaterThan(-0.5)
  .NumberLessThan(0.5)
  .build();
filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(20, filterCriteriaT); // Columna T

// Ordenar la columna S5 de Z a A
headersRange.sort([{column: 19, ascending: false}]);
```

Filter Criteria

Filter in column S5:S for values ​​greater than 60%

Filter in column T5:T by values ​​between -50% and 50%

Sort column S5:S from Z to A (ascending false)

Comment: Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you?

Comment: What is `the desired criteria`?

Comment: Filter Criteria 

Filter in column S5:S for values ​​greater than 60%

Filter in column T5:T by values ​​between -50% and 50%

Sort column S5:S from Z to A (ascending false)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your actual expected result and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your updated question, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please set your sheet name.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (filter) {
    filter.remove();
  }
  sheet
    .getRange("S5:T")
    .createFilter()
    .setColumnFilterCriteria(19, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberGreaterThan(0.6).build())
    .setColumnFilterCriteria(20, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberGreaterThan(-0.5).whenNumberLessThan(0.5).build());
  sheet.getRange("M5:X").sort({ column: 19, ascending: false });
}
```

- I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected condition. So, if the above modification was not your expected result, please modify the condition.

  - `.whenNumberGreaterThan(0.6)` might be `.whenNumberGreaterThanOrEqualTo(0.6)`?
  - `.whenNumberGreaterThan(-0.5).whenNumberLessThan(0.5)` might be `.whenNumberGreaterThan(0.5).whenNumberLessThan(-0.5)` or `whenNumberBetween(-0.5, 0.5)` or `whenNumberBetween(0.5, -0.5)`?
- From your script of `headersRange.sort([{column: 19, ascending: false}]);` where `headersRange` is `sheet.getRange("M5:X5");`, in this case, that is `sheet.getRange("M5:X").sort([{column: 19, ascending: false}]);` or `sheet.getDataRange().sort({column: 19, ascending: false});`?

#### References:

- [createFilter()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createfilter)
- [Class Filter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter)

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: @Franco Vera Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.